# Does a 2-stroke engine needs "break-in" after replacing cylinder and piston?

Tags: two-stroke, piston, cylinder, break-in, trimmer

I just replaced cylinder and piston (with new gasket, rings, etc) in a 2-stroke 52cc string trimmer engine. It started at the first pull and sounds great, I let it run for 5 minutes, adjusted the carb and turned it off, waited for it to cool down and tighten everything again just to be sure.

Tomorrow I will need to use it to cut some grass, do I need to follow some special procedure? Like running it for less time than I usually do, limit the wot, use more oil in the mix, etc, or can I use it normally?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Great question. I don't think you'd need to do more than what you've done. You might want to run a rich mixture (more oil in your fuel) for the first real run of it, but I wouldn't know for sure. You got me thinking now! :o)

Comment: When you buy a new 'strimmer' etc, you don't run the new engine in, so I would presume that you wouldn't need to run in the new cylinder and piston.

Comment: Use it normally without "being mean" to it. Make sure you are using good fuel and oil. Main thing id be watching for is over heating. So use it for short periods then give it a chance to cool down.